# Discounts for multiple price field selections (e.g. select all five options and get $X off)

Tags: civievent, price-sets, cividiscount

Is it possible to set up a price set such that selecting multiple options would lower the total price?

Our use case is a summer camp. You can register for a day ($50) or for a week ($190). We need to be able to set a maximum number of participants for each day. So, if we could make a form where you simply select all days in the week to register for an entire week and a $60 discount was applied in that case, this would satisfy our requirements.

Putting in the week as a separate option would make it impossible to have registration limits for each day. The camp has multiple weeks over the summer, so we can't use a registration limit for the whole event to do this.

This is currently set up as a webform, but that comes with other issues, so it would be preferable to find an option that works with price sets and CiviEvent.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create the price set with 5 individual day options each at $50 and a 'Full week discount' at -$60 and then add javascript to hide the discount option and set it when all 5 days are selected.

As a javascript approach that is open to someone messing with it and selecting the discount option when they should not so you might want to add a check on the server side as well - depends a bit on your audience.

Comment: Interesting idea, I think this could work and I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you are looking for, but you can use civi discounts extension and have set a discount code. 
(the code would work for anyone with the code.) 
Maybe you can set up with webforms a conditional logic that will pop-up a field that will only show the discount code once x amount of days are selected, I don't use Drupal so I don't know if that is an option.

Comment: In this case, there are eight different weeks, so there would have to be eight different discounts, which would be unwieldy.